# Searching in SQL Server database with string from C# program

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to search on my database with the following stored procedure:

```
@niveau varchar(50),
@naam varchar(50)

)
as
begin transaction
if (LEN(@naam) > 0 and LEN(@niveau) > 0)
select * from Opleiding where OpleidingNaam like '%' + @naam + '%' and OpleidingNiveau like '%' + @niveau + '%'

else if (LEN(@naam) > 0 and LEN(@niveau) = 0 )
select * from Opleiding where OpleidingNaam like '%' + @naam + '%'

else if (LEN(@naam) = 0 and LEN(@niveau) > 0 )
select * from Opleiding where OpleidingNiveau like '%' + @niveau + '%' 

else if (LEN(@naam) = 0 and LEN(@niveau) = 0 )
select * from Opleiding ;
```

The reason for the if/if else statements is because I want to search with name (`@naam`) or level (`@niveau`), any combination should be possible (like leave one blank etc).

Now the problem I have is I can search "m" like this:

[image: search: "m"]

and I get a job with level MBO so that is good I guess. But when I search the full job level like "MBO" like this:

[image: search: "MBO"]

I get nothing.

This is a test I did in my database to simulate the string I get from my application:

```
declare @naam varchar(50);
declare @niveau varchar(50);

set @naam = '';
set @niveau = 'MBO';


if (LEN(@naam) > 0 and LEN(@niveau) > 0)
select * from Opleiding where OpleidingNaam like '%' + @naam + '%' and OpleidingNiveau like '%' + @niveau + '%'

else if (LEN(@naam) > 0 and LEN(@niveau) = 0 )
select * from Opleiding where OpleidingNaam like '%' + @naam + '%'

else if (LEN(@naam) = 0 and LEN(@niveau) > 0 )
select * from Opleiding where OpleidingNiveau like '%' + @niveau + '%' 

else if (LEN(@naam) = 0 and LEN(@niveau) = 0 )
select * from Opleiding ;
```

and as you can see it should return the job I want.

This is how I fill my listbox:

```
 public void laadGegevens()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand zoeken = new SqlCommand("spSelecteerOpleidingenList", conn);
            zoeken.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            zoeken.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naam", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(txtNaam.Text);
            zoeken.Parameters.AddWithValue("@niveau", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(txtNiveau.Text);
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = zoeken.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    foreach (IDataRecord record in reader)
                    {
                        ListOpleidingen.Items.Add(string.Format(reader[1].ToString() + " " + reader[2].ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

If you have any idea what I'm doing wrong please let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I would double check which textbox is txtNaam and which is txtNiveau in the GUI.

Comment: @marc_s I'm using Microsoft sql-server, added the tag thx for telling !

Comment: @AntonínLejsek i checked both textboxes and the values.text i used in the parameters from the sqlcommand and they seem to be correct.

Comment: Do NOT post images of your code.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn why is that a problem ? it's a project for school so no sensitive data.

Comment: As @JoelCoehoorn stated you should post your code via copy and paste and not by image.  The editor allows you to select and mark your code lines as code using {} (and other means) which will make it easier for us to read, edit, and mimick to help you.

Comment: You can post the code, but posting it as an image is more work for you and makes it MUCH harder for us to help you. Just paste the code and use the button on the toolbar so it will come out formatted nicely.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII i see, this is my first post so i didn't really think about that. I'll have to edit it.

Comment: @Lars [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Just a remark, I don't see the point of a transaction & rollback of changes just for a select.

Comment: 1/2 hour later, still no edit, voting to close.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn i added my code now, sorry that it took a while, doing lots of things at the same time at the moment.

Comment: @LukStorms very true got rid of that part, thx !

Comment: Why are you using ExecuteReader?  A stored procedure should be using ExecuteNonQuery.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @jdweng ExecuteNonQuery doesn't work if i want to fill a listbox with a foreach loop. Since i don't want to use a listview (which would be easier), ill have to use a reader for that. The example in your link also uses a reader.

Comment: Have a look at sql server profiler, what is the query you send to the server. That should help you find yout which part of the task is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have confused two different approaches for passing parameters. The code is doing:

```
zoeken.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naam", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(txtNaam.Text);
zoeken.Parameters.AddWithValue("@niveau", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(txtNiveau.Text);
```

which is setting the `SqlDbType.VarChar` enum **as a value**, before the value is overwritten but you probably meant:

```
zoeken.Parameters.Add("@naam", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(txtNaam.Text);
zoeken.Parameters.Add("@niveau", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(txtNiveau.Text);
```

Some other tips:

1. Worth reading [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).
2. SqlCommand is IDisposable so should be in a `using` block.
3. The connection is also IDisposable, so rather than hold that as a field, consider having it as a local variable in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need the `finally...Close`, since the implicit Dispose as it exits the block will do that.
4. The stored procedure definition at the top of the question is incomplete, but it's a good idea to wrap the whole body in `BEGIN...END`. Perhaps that's what you meant where you have `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, since that seems out of place in a procedure which just does a `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!
As for your change in my code, it didn't make a difference sadly. 
I also tried to add the length for the varchar like: "("@naam", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)"
but that also didn't do it.